# Custom naming in router resources

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

i have in my controller

```
public function details($id)
    {
        $claim = Claim::findOrFail($id);
        $details = $claim->details;

        return response()->json([], 200);
    }
```

and I have in my routes

```
Route::resource('claims', 'Admin\\ClaimsController',['names'=> ['details'=>'admin.claims.details'], 'only' => ['index','store','update','destroy','details']]);
```

when I run `php artisan route:list` i do not see the admin.claims.details( admin/claims/1/details) in the list

the documentation is pretty vague here so I'm asking how to properly set a custom route? How do I specify if its "POST" or "GET"?

Answer (score 1):

To override the default resource controller actions' route names, you can pass a names array with your options.

For example:

```
Route::resource('claims', 'ControllerClassName', [
    'names' => [
        'index' => 'admin.claims.details',
        'create' => 'admin.claims.create',
        // etc...
    ], 
    'only' => [
        'index','store','update','destroy','details'
    ]
]);
```

REF: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-naming-resource-routes

Here are examples of setting custom named get/post routes.

GET Route

```
Route::get('claims', ['as' => 'admin.claims.details', uses => 'ControllerClassName']);
```

POST Route

```
Route::post('claims', ['as' => 'admin.claims.details', uses => 'ControllerClassName']);
```

REF: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#named-routes

Comment: Ohh! I think I misunderstood the use case for "router naming" I have a method "details" for which I want to use "/admin/claims/{id}/details" as a route to the controller method.

Comment: You can use `Route::get('admin/claims/{id}/details', ['as' => 'admin.claims.details', uses => 'ControllerClassName@details']);
` and in your controller details method you'll have access to the `$id` variable.